# For a given list of string count no of words

Tags: python

I have a given list of string which is:

```
strings = ["the method of lagrange multipliers is the economists workhorse for solving optimization problems", "the technique is a centerpiece of economic theory but unfortunately its usually taught poorly"]
```

Now I want to find the no of word in each sentence so that my output will be

```
{'the': 2, 'method': 1, 'of': 1, 'lagrange': 1, 'multipliers': 1, 'is': 1, 'economists': 1, 'workhorse': 1, 'for': 1, 'solving': 1, 'optimization': 1, 'problems': 1}

{'the': 1, 'technique': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'centerpiece': 1, 'of': 1, 'economic': 1, 'theory': 1, 'but': 1, 'unfortunately': 1, 'its': 1, 'usually': 1, 'taught': 1, 'poorly': 1}
```

My code is as below:

```
from collections import Counter

dataset = ["the method of lagrange multipliers is the economists workhorse for solving optimization problems",
           "the technique is a centerpiece of economic theory but unfortunately its usually taught poorly"]


for index,row in enumerate(dataset):
    word_frequency = dict(Counter(row.split(" ")))
    
print(word_frequency)
```

With this i am getting output which is:

```
{'the': 1, 'technique': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'centerpiece': 1, 'of': 1, 'economic': 1, 'theory': 1, 'but': 1, 'unfortunately': 1, 'its': 1, 'usually': 1, 'taught': 1, 'poorly': 1}
```

Clearly it's only considering the second sentence and counting it but not the first one.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong in my code?

Comment: that's because you are overwriting your first counter

Comment: Your ```word_frequency``` is getting reset every time. You can either move ```print(word_frequency)``` inside the loop or add the dictionary to a list

Comment: A simple way is to make a list of counters: `counts = [Counter(row) for row in map(str.split, dataset) ]`

Answer (score 0):

The `word_frequency` is being updated with every string in the dataset list.In the end , it is storing the Counter for last string in the dataset.Hence, displaying the the Counter for words in the last string. You can use `print(word_frequency)` inside the for loop or use a `list`  and append the `word_frequency` to the list each time and once you are out of the loop just print the `list`.

```
from collections import Counter

dataset = ["the method of lagrange multipliers is the economists workhorse for solving optimization problems",
           "the technique is a centerpiece of economic theory but unfortunately its usually taught poorly"]

l = []
for index,row in enumerate(dataset):
    word_frequency = dict(Counter(row.split(" ")))
    l.append(word_frequency)
    
print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just move the print to be inside your `for` loop as you're overwriting your calculated word_frequency parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Print inside the loop instead of setting a variable inside the loop (which will get overwritten on each iteration before you print it at the end):

```
>>> dataset = ["the method of lagrange multipliers is the economists workhorse for solving optimization problems",
...            "the technique is a centerpiece of economic theory but unfortunately its usually taught poorly"]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> for sentence in dataset:
...     print(dict(Counter(sentence.split())))
...
{'the': 2, 'method': 1, 'of': 1, 'lagrange': 1, 'multipliers': 1, 'is': 1, 'economists': 1, 'workhorse': 1, 'for': 1, 'solving': 1, 'optimization': 1, 'problems': 1}
{'the': 1, 'technique': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'centerpiece': 1, 'of': 1, 'economic': 1, 'theory': 1, 'but': 1, 'unfortunately': 1, 'its': 1, 'usually': 1, 'taught': 1, 'poorly': 1}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're overwriting the `word_frequency` variable inside the `for` loop, meaning only the final value from the final count is printed.

You should instead define a `Counter` outside the for loop, add to the values of that using Counter's [add](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html#arithmetic) functionality within the for loop, then convert to dict and print at the end:

```py
from collections import Counter

dataset = ["the method of lagrange multipliers is the economists workhorse for solving optimization problems",
           "the technique is a centerpiece of economic theory but unfortunately its usually taught poorly"]

cumulative_counter = Counter()
for index,row in enumerate(dataset):
  cumulative_counter += Counter(row.split(" "))

word_frequency = dict(cumulative_counter)
print(word_frequency)
```

Outputs:

> `{'the': 3, 'method': 1, 'of': 2, 'lagrange': 1, 'multipliers': 1, 'is': 2, 'economists': 1, 'workhorse': 1, 'for': 1, 'solving': 1, 'optimization': 1, 'problems': 1, 'technique': 1, 'a': 1, 'centerpiece': 1, 'economic': 1, 'theory': 1, 'but': 1, 'unfortunately': 1, 'its': 1, 'usually': 1, 'taught': 1, 'poorly': 1}`